# How to get matplotlib to place lines accurately?

Tags: python, matplotlib

By default, matplotlib plot can place lines very inaccurately.

For example, see the placement of the left endpoint in the attached plot. There's at least a whole pixel of air that shouldn't be there. In fact I think the line center is 2 pixels off.

How to get matplotlib to draw **accurately**? I don't mind if there is some performance hit.

Inaccurately rendered line in matplotlib plot:

[image: inaccurately rendered line in matplotlib plot]

Inaccurately rendered line in matplotlib plot - detail magnified:

[image: inaccurately rendered line in matplotlib plot - detail magnified]

This was made with the default installations in Ubuntu 16.04 (Python 3), Jupyter notebook (similar result from command line).

Mathematica, for comparison, does subpixel-perfect rendering directly and by default:
[image: Same thing rendered by Mathematica]
Why can't we?

Comment: Could it be that the x-limits begins on the outer side of the axis, i.e. plotting from x=1 with a slope will give a slight off-set at x=width_of_axis?  Try putting a slightly smaller x-low-limit, like `ax.set_xlim([0.9999, 3.0001])` .

Comment: Turn the dpi up.  This looks like low dpi + pixel snapping issues.

Comment: Moving the lower xlim to 0.99 might work visually in this case, but moving the goalposts is really cheating, and isn't a general solution.

Comment: This was apparently solved by using Cairo, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48979691/sub-pixel-accuracy-scatter-plots-with-matplotlib

Answer (score 3):

Consider the following to see what is going on

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 4], clip_on=False, lw=5, alpha=.5)
ax.set_xlim([1, 3])

fig.savefig('so.png', dpi=400)
```

[image: example]

You can also disable pixel snapping by passing `snap=False` to `plot`, however once you get down to placing ~ single pixel wide line, you are going to have issues because the underlying rasterization is too coarse.

Comment: I agree that we can get an accurate rendering by making a giant image and then shrinking it for display. But that is awkward, inefficient, and indirect.

If Mathematica can do subpixel-perfect rendering by default (see image I'll attach to the question), why can't we? It's embarrassing!

Comment: I didn't find snap=False helped noticeably.

Comment: Almost two years later, this issue is still persistent. I cannot believe that there is no one to tackle this problem, since it is a major issue for a plotting module.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is even more notorious when one plots functions which are symmetric with respect to the x axis and slowly approach zero. As for example here: [image]

which is indeed embarrassing if you are telling the reader of a scientific paper that the two curves are symmetric!

I went around this problem by exporting to pdf instead of exporting to png:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I completely agree that this should be worked on. I find that `plt.plot` gives (at least more or less) unshifted lines (in Jupyter) by calling `plt.figure` with `dpi=144` (the default is 72). The figures do become twice as big though...