# Sub-pixel accuracy scatter plots with matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, antialiasing

**Note: I figured out a solution to this question while writing it. My answer is below.**

Is there an easy way to get sub-pixel antialiased placement of circles using matplotlib? I was able to create the following .gif but the fact that the motion of the circles steps by integer pixels is really bugging me.

[image]

I can of course render a large image (`plt.savefig("image.png",dpi=1000)`) and scale down, but the added complexity is a pain (this is an example for students, so importing extra tools will annoy the students and installing extra tools will annoy campus IT!)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from math import sin,cos
x=[]
y=[]
#Create 41**2 particles in the unit square
for i in range(41):
    for j in range(41):
        x.append(i*0.05-1.0)
        y.append(j*0.05-1.0)
#5 second video at 30 fps = 150 frames
for n in range(150):
    plt.close('all')
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(figsize=(5,5))
    #some cool motion
    for i in range(len(x)):
        x[i]+=0.001*cos(x[i]+3*y[i])
        y[i]+=0.001*sin(6*x[i]-4*y[i])
    #create the scatter plot
    axes.scatter(x,y,s=3,antialiased=True)
    axes.set_xlim(-1.4,1.4)
    axes.set_ylim(-1.4,1.4)
    axes.set_aspect('equal')
    plt.savefig("out/fig%03d.png"%n,dpi=80)
```

Comment: There is an issue about this undesired behaviour on GitHub. I added [your example](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/7233#issuecomment-373967684) in a little modified form to the discussion, since it was claimed there that using the Cairo backend would not have this problem, while I still see it using Cairo, although only in the saved version of the animation, not on screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be interested in https://github.com/anntzer/mplcairo, a new cairo-based backend for Matplotlib which I originally wrote *exactly* because I was unhappy with this issue.  It does not display the aforementioned problem, while maintaining reasonable performance.

Comment: Only drawback: It does not seem to work with python 2.

Comment: But the main point of this answer being that using `mpl_cairo` would be faster than using the current cairo backend with [your fix](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/10828/files) (as proposed in my answer), is that correct?

Comment: It is *much* faster, yes (and does not have any of the many bugs displayed by the builtin cairo backend, as discussed on the mpl tracker).
I have no interest in making it work with Py2 (and will not accept PRs for that either).

Comment: can this be merged into matplotlib where people can use it easily?

Comment: It's unlikely to happen soon.  Note that you can "just" pip install mplcairo right now and it should work for you; please file an issue on the bug tracker if there's any problems with the install.

Answer (score 4):

The scatter function must be optimized to just do quick integer placement. If you manually add Circle objects, the sub-pixel antialiasing is handled for you. It's quite a bit slower. Example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection
from math import sin,cos
x=[]
y=[]
#Create 41**2 particles in the unit square
for i in range(41):
    for j in range(41):
        x.append(i*0.05-1.0)
        y.append(j*0.05-1.0)
#5 second video at 30 fps = 150 frames
for n in range(150):
    plt.close('all')
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(figsize=(5,5))
    #adding the Circles to the plot using a PatchCollection is much faster.
    patches=[]
    #some cool motion
    for i in range(len(x)):
        x[i]+=0.001*cos(x[i]+3*y[i])
        y[i]+=0.001*sin(6*x[i]-4*y[i])
        patches.append(plt.Circle((x[i],y[i]),0.015))
    axes.add_collection(PatchCollection(patches, alpha=0.95))
    axes.set_xlim(-1.4,1.4)
    axes.set_ylim(-1.4,1.4)
    axes.set_aspect('equal')
    plt.savefig("out/fig%03d.png"%n,dpi=80)
```

The result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is based in the scatter marker stamping of the Agg backend. There is [this issue](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/7233) about it, which is still unsolved.

However, using the Cairo backend, the issue is not present.

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkCairo") # or Qt4Cairo, Qt5Cairo
```

However, there is an issue with saving the animation. This is fixed in [this PR](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/10828/files). Hence, an option is to replace your `backend_cairo.py` with the fixed version and use the Cairo backend.

The following would be an example which uses the animtion module, such that the animation can be observed live on screen as well as easily saved:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkCairo")
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

x, y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-1,1,31),np.linspace(-1,1,31))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(2.8,2.8))
fig.subplots_adjust(.02,.02,.98,.9)
ax.set_title("scatter")

### Scatter
sc = ax.scatter(x,y,s=2)

ax.axis("off")
ax.set_xlim(-1.2,1.2)
ax.set_ylim(-1.2,1.2)
ax.set_aspect('equal')

def generator():
    X=np.copy(x); Y=np.copy(y)
    for i in range(100):
        X += 0.0015*np.cos(x+3*y)
        Y += 0.0015*np.sin(6*x-4*y)
        yield (X,Y)

def animate(i): 
    x,y = i
    # update scatter
    sc.set_offsets(np.c_[x.flatten(),y.flatten()])

ani = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=generator, interval=50, repeat=False)
ani.save("skewedgrid_scatter.gif", writer="imagemagick")
plt.show()
```

[image]