# Marker position without pixel decision?

Tags: python, matplotlib

If I set the position of small matplotlib markers they have to "decide" which pixel to choose. I think this is not the case in Matlab, and markers can be located in between pixels with both pixels sharing the brightness.

In the attached example the marker on my screen does not perform a smooth circle but jumps between pixels. In Matlab this circle would look smooth. Can I achieve the same using matplotlib?

```
import tkinter as tk
import os
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import time

class Plotwindow():
    def __init__(self, root, size):
        self.root = root
        self.fig = Figure(size, constrained_layout=True)
        self.ax = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig, master=root.plot_frame)
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()

    def clear(self):
        self.ax.cla()

    def plot(self, x, y):
        self.ax.scatter(x, y, marker='o', s=2, color='black', snap=False)
        self.ax.set_xlim(20*np.array([-1, 1]))
        self.ax.set_ylim(20*np.array([-1, 1]))
        self.canvas.draw()
        self.canvas.flush_events()
        
class NewGUI():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.resizable(False, False)
        self.root.geometry("405x405+400+200")

        self.button = tk.Button(self.root, text="Move", command=self.move)
        self.button.pack(side='top', fill='x')
        self.button = tk.Button(self.root, text="Hold", command=self.hold)
        self.button.pack(side='top', fill='x')

        self.plot_frame = tk.Frame()
        self.plot_frame.pack(side='bottom', fill='x')
        self.plot_window = Plotwindow(self, (15,15))
        self.plot_window.plot(1,0)

        self.root.mainloop()

    def move(self):
        for i in range(20):
            self.plot_window.clear()
            time.sleep(0.01)
            phi = 2*np.pi*i/20
            x = np.cos(phi)
            y = np.sin(phi)
            self.plot_window.plot(x,y)

    def hold(self):
        for i in range(20):
            phi = 2*np.pi*i/20
            x = np.cos(phi)
            y = np.sin(phi)
            self.plot_window.plot(x,y)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    new = NewGUI()
```

Comment: Set snap=False.

Comment: This is indeed the issue I have, but it doesn't help... still snapping? (edited the code)

Comment: Last comment of the first answer of this question says in 2018 that the snapping problem is not yet solved, is it still impossible in 2021?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39183658/how-to-get-matplotlib-to-place-lines-accurately

Comment: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/8746 Maybe comment there?  I suspect if you try mpl-Cairo this is not a problem.  Of course increasing the dpi is often a good solution

Comment: Posted this as an answer, thank you very much! Looks much better with the cairo backend!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comment by Jody Klymak I got what I wanted with the cairo backend even without snap=False, see attachement.

```
import tkinter as tk
import os
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
matplotlib.use('TkCairo')
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkcairo import FigureCanvasTkCairo
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import time

class Plotwindow():
    def __init__(self, root, size):
        self.root = root
        self.fig = Figure(size, constrained_layout=True)
        self.ax = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkCairo(self.fig, master=root.plot_frame)
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()

    def clear(self):
        self.ax.cla()

    def plot(self, x, y):
        self.ax.scatter(x, y, marker='o', s=2, color='black')
        self.ax.set_xlim(20*np.array([-1, 1]))
        self.ax.set_ylim(20*np.array([-1, 1]))
        self.canvas.draw()
        self.canvas.flush_events()
        
class NewGUI():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.resizable(False, False)
        self.root.geometry("405x405+400+200")

        self.button = tk.Button(self.root, text="Move", command=self.move)
        self.button.pack(side='top', fill='x')
        self.button = tk.Button(self.root, text="Hold", command=self.hold)
        self.button.pack(side='top', fill='x')

        self.plot_frame = tk.Frame()
        self.plot_frame.pack(side='bottom', fill='x')
        self.plot_window = Plotwindow(self, (15,15))
        self.plot_window.plot(1,0)

        self.root.mainloop()

    def move(self):
        for i in range(20):
            self.plot_window.clear()
            time.sleep(0.01)
            phi = 2*np.pi*i/20
            x = np.cos(phi)
            y = np.sin(phi)
            self.plot_window.plot(x,y)

    def hold(self):
        for i in range(20):
            phi = 2*np.pi*i/20
            x = np.cos(phi)
            y = np.sin(phi)
            self.plot_window.plot(x,y)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    new = NewGUI()
```