# Matplotlib lines appear not to be accurate when plotting to Pdf

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, pdf

It appears that there are some very small inaccuracies when using `plt.plot()` for generating Pdfs with Matplotlib.
In the following I have some simple examples, where lines plotted with `plt.plot()` are not aligned with the original data points plotted with `plt.scatter()`. The differences are small but could still be noticed in papers etc. when looking closely at the Pdf. I am using Matplotlib 3.6.1.

##### Example 1:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as mlp
mlp.use("Agg")
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv("my_data.csv")

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(1.5,1.5))
plt.plot(df['X'], df['Y'], color='b', linewidth=0.1)
plt.scatter(df['X'], df['Y'], color='k', s=0.05, linewidths=0)
fig.savefig("res.pdf")
fig.savefig("res.png", dpi=5000)
```

This is the resulting Pdf:
[Pdf plot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/acddN.png)

Let's zoom in on some details in the Pdf (the black points and blue lines are not aligned):
[Pdf plot 1 zoomed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GzdTO.png)

The same segment in the Png (everything is aligned):
[Png plot 1 zoomed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7aS5.png)

##### Example 2:

The same effect can be reached with generated data:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mlp
mlp.use("Agg")
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(1.0,1.5))
X = np.arange(0,12,0.01)
data = np.sin(X) + np.random.normal(0, 0.005, (len(X),))
plt.plot(X, data, color='b', linewidth=0.06)
plt.scatter(X, data, color='k', s=0.05, linewidths=0)
fig.savefig("res.pdf")
```

This is the resulting Pdf: [Pdf plot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nRsWC.png)

Let's zoom in on some details in the Pdf (the black points and blue lines are not aligned): [Pdf plot 2 zoomed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nd9Of.png)

##### Example 3

The mentioned deviations are small, but are actually visible in some real-world examples. In the following plot, I have used `plt.fill_between()` and plotted the very same lines using `plt.plot()`. In this case, the inaccuracies of the lines would be directly visible in the Pdf without zooming in:
[Pdf plot 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdcDW.png)

###### Question:

To me this behavior is quite surprising. The PNG plot (with high DPI) does not show the misalignment. What is going on here? Changing the backend does not seem to improve results.
Is there some way of making these plots more 'accurate'?

Similar question: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39183658/how-to-get-matplotlib-to-place-lines-accurately)

Comment: Have you tried a different PDF renderer?

Comment: @norok2 I have tried AGG, PDF and PGF backends. With PGF the alignment seems to be slightly better, but still not good. Do you have any recommendation for a backend?

Comment: I think you should stick to PDF for MPL renderer. I mean to try a different PDF viewer to render the screenshot

Comment: @norok2 Yes, I have used the Adobe Acrobat Reader and also tested viewing in Firefox browser and SumatraPdf. They all look the same. Even importing to Inkscape did give the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out Matplotlib does a simplification of paths when the figure is small and the data are very dense, see details [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/24260) and [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/performance.html#line-segment-simplification).

> The simplification works by iteratively merging line segments into a single vector until the next line segment's perpendicular distance to the vector (measured in display-coordinate space) is greater than the `path.simplify_threshold parameter`.
> Matplotlib currently defaults to a conservative simplification threshold of 1/9.

To improve plotting accuracy in small plots, change the threshold to a small value, e.g.

```
mlp.rcParams["path.simplify_threshold"] = 0.01
```

or just turn off path simplification:

```
mpl.rcParams['path.simplify'] = False
```